# NuxtJS2 and Cloudinary Upload API: How to delete asset from Cloudinary?

Tags: nuxt.js, cloudinary

I am new to using the Cloudinary API with NuxtJS. How do you delete an image/asset from your Cloudinary account with a NuxtJS app?

Here's what I tried:

`modules/cloudinary/index.js`: (create the security signature and config info)

```
import { createHash } from 'crypto'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

export default function () {
  const config = this.options.privateRuntimeConfig.cloudinary

  this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', (app) => {
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use('/api/cloudinary/signature', setSignature)
  })

  function setSignature(req, res) {
    try {
      const sha1 = createHash('sha1')
      const payload = []

      Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => {
        payload.push(`${key}=${req.body[key]}`)
      })

      sha1.update(payload.sort().join('&') + config.apiSecret)
      res.end(
        JSON.stringify({
          signature: sha1.digest('hex')
        })
      )
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}
```

`DeleteImage.vue`:

```
<script> 
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary' <--// Node SDK: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      src: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async deleteFile() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/cloudinary/signature', {
        method: 'POST',
        // body: JSON.stringify(options),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })

      const signature = response.json.signature
      console.log(signature) // <-- console logging here gets me the signature
      try {
        const asset = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(this.src, signature)
        console.log(asset)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error deleting image', error)
      }
    },
    
  }
}
</script>
```

I now get the console error:

```
cloudinary.js?9447:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Object.eval (cloudinary.js?9447:1)
    at eval (cloudinary.js:10)
    at Object../node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js (app.js:5178)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
    at eval (index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/UploaderImage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:30)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/UploaderImage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1546)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
    at eval (UploaderImage.vue?9448:1)
```

I have no idea what I am doing. Sorry!

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? You can delete it from Cloudinary's dashboard. The destroy method looks like adapted to your use case: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method

Comment: Trying to understand…can I use that API in a regular SFC or needs to be setup in some kind of plugin?

Comment: UPdated my question with my attempt. I have no idea what I am doing, sorry. Am I not allowed to import Node SDKs into VUE files like that?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting resources from your Cloudinary account can be done either via the [Destroy API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method) (for single-file deletions), or the [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources) (for bulk-deletions). However, both require you to use your account's `api_secret`. As it's really not recommended to include your account's `api_secret` in your client-side code, deleting resources using these two APIs should be done from the server-side.

Having said that, it's also possible to delete from the client-side via an automatically-expired token (up to 10 minutes from the upload time). For more information:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#deleting_client_side_uploaded_assets

Comment: Yes I know it can be done from server side , but how to set it up in Nuxt? I see the nuxt cloudinary module only allows uploads, not deletion.

Comment: The current Cloudinary Nuxt module indeed excludes any of the deletion methods. You can deploy your own server API and call it from Vue.js using an HTTP client like fetch or axios.

Comment: Not sure how to deploy my own server api with Nuxt. Maybe this? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/